# Cloned an HD to a slightly smaller SSD, how do i make it "aware" of it's new size?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

Yesterday cloned my HD to my new SSD via `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sda`, they had a difference of about 20GiB, so i knew that in the end it would with an error of not enough space.
I did it and it worked, my Windows partitions are working as expected, since i could only not fully copy my Manjaro partitions. However it still claims to have the same disk space as the old HD, and not the new smaller space of the SSD, not only that, but i can't remove my last three partitions (Manjaro's EFI Bootloader, root and SWAP respectivelly) in Windows Partition Manager as it pops up an error claiming "Invalid Parameter".

That being my problem, how do i:

1. Make it "aware" of it's new size?
2. Remove the last corrupted partitions?

Comment: Who downvoted all answers here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best tool for doing this is the [GNOME partition editor.](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you used `dd` rather than one of the numerous
[free disk cloning products](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm).
Most of these products can well manage different target and source
disk sizes.

To solve the problem,
enter Disk Management and resize the disk to slightly below its maximum size.
Windows should then rediscover the real disk size.